# An item with the same key has already been added-No duplicate column in query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I run the SSRS report in SharePoint it runs fine, but when I try to execute it in the development environment, it results in a blank report. No data is displaying.

And also when I am trying to refresh the fields of the dataset used in this report, I am unable to refresh. It is showing the error "could not update a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct" and when the details is showing as "An item with the same key has already been added"

I have checked for my datasource connection and it is fine and I could not find anything wrong with my SQL query also. It is giving correct result when I am running it as query. And I also checked in query that I have used no column as duplicate while using alias.

Answer (score -1):

Probably there is some kind of duplicate column name, try to put your whole dataset query as subquery 
example: select * from ( [query from ssrs dataset] )ssrs.
Execute such statement in mssql and see if there is an error.